What might be causing ERROR 999999 - Request Entity Too Large. (status code 413)
I wrote a custom geoprocessing tool that was originally designed to use a single shapefile of a a county parcel dataset, but was recently changed to be able to use a hosted feature layer of a nationwide parcel dataset instead. I think that might be what is causing my error, but it seemed to work last week and now it doesn't, so I'm not entirely sure what is going on since I have not changed the tool at all between now and when it was last working.
Any idea how to fix this?
Here is an image of the error:

Here is an image of the code block where the error is occuring:

The full code is shown below:

import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
handlerID = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
jpgPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
regrid = 'Regrid Nationwide Parcel Data'
SitePoints = "Facility Points"
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
listLayers = aprxMap.listLayers()
areaNameDescription = "Property parcel(s) boundary for facility address, selected through GIS 
analysis in 2024. Multiple contiguous parcels at this address share a common owner name."


# points def query
for lyr in listLayers:
    if lyr.name == SitePoints:
        lyr.definitionQuery = f"HANDLER_ID = '{handlerID}'"
# get handlerName
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(SitePoints, 'HANDLER_NAME')
for row in cursor:
    handlerName = row[0].replace(" ", "_")
    
# Process: Select Layer By Location (Select Layer By Location)(management)
RCRA_Site_Parcel_Overlap_Selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(regrid, 
"INTERSECT", SitePoints)
count1 = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(RCRA_Site_Parcel_Overlap_Selection).getOutput(0))
if count1 == 0:
    arcpy.AddError("No site points intersect the boundary you have selected. \n Please 
complete the rest of the analysis manually. \n")
else:
    cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(RCRA_Site_Parcel_Overlap_Selection, 'owner')
    for row in cursor:
        ownerName = row[0]
if not ownerName:
    arcpy.AddError("No owner name was found. \n Please complete the rest of the analysis 
manually. \n")
# Make new feature class of selected parcels
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(RCRA_Site_Parcel_Overlap_Selection, 
arcpy.env.workspace, "parcelOverlapSelection")
# Select initial adjacent parcels
initialAdj = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(regrid, "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", 
"parcelOverlapSelection")
query = "owner = " + "'" + ownerName + "'"
ownerSelect = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(initialAdj, '', query)
prevCount = 0
curCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(ownerSelect).getOutput(0))
if curCount == 0:
    # Add join
    points = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(SitePoints, "INTERSECT", 
RCRA_Site_Parcel_Overlap_Selection)
    # Spatial Join
    arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(
        target_features="parcelOverlapSelection",
        join_features=points,
        out_feature_class=handlerName,
        join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY",
        field_mapping="Coordinate \"Coordinate\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,Coordinate,0,255;HANDLER_ID \"HANDLER_ID\" true true false 
255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,HANDLER_ID,0,255;HANDLER_NAME \"HANDLER_NAME\" 
true true false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,HANDLER_NAME,0,255;LONGITUDE 
\"LONGITUDE\" true true false 8 Double 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,LONGITUDE,-1,-1;LATITUDE \"LATITUDE\" true true false 8 
Double 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,LATITUDE,-1,-1;ACTIVITY_LOCATION 
\"ACTIVITY_LOCATION\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,ACTIVITY_LOCATION,0,255;REGION \"REGION\" true true false 4 
Long 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,REGION,-1,-1;CONTACT_CITY \"CONTACT_CITY\" true true 
false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,CONTACT_CITY,0,255;CONTACT_STREET1 
\"CONTACT_STREET1\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,CONTACT_STREET1,0,255;LOCATION_COUNTY_NAME 
\"LOCATION_COUNTY_NAME\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,LOCATION_COUNTY_NAME,0,255;CONTACT_STREET_NO 
\"CONTACT_STREET_NO\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,CONTACT_STREET_NO,0,255;Lat_Long \"Lat_Long\" true true 
false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,Lat_Long,0,255")  
    # Edit Symbology
    aprxMap.addDataFromPath(arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + handlerName)
    poly = aprxMap.listLayers(handlerName)[0]
    sym = poly.symbology
    sym.updateRenderer('SimpleRenderer')
    sym.renderer.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery('Black Outline')
    sym.renderer.symbol.size = 2
    poly.symbology = sym
    # Zoom to layer
    cam = aprx.activeView.camera
    ext = arcpy.Describe(handlerName).extent
    cam.setExtent(ext)
    # Export map to image
    for lyr in listLayers:
        if lyr.name == "parcelOverlapSelection":
            aprxMap.removeLayer(lyr)
    aprxMap.clearSelection()
    aprxMap.defaultView.exportToJPEG(jpgPath + "\\" + handlerName, 1221, 835)
# Loop through and find additional adjacent parcels
isDone = False
while curCount > 0 and isDone == False:
    addAdj = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(regrid, "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES", ownerSelect, 
'', 'ADD_TO_SELECTION')
    ownerSelect = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(addAdj, '', query)
    prevCount = curCount
    curCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(ownerSelect).getOutput(0))
    if prevCount == curCount:
        isDone = True

    adjacentSelection = arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(ownerSelect, 
arcpy.env.workspace, "RCRASitePropertyParcels")
    # Get parcel numbers
    parcelList = []
    rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("RCRASitePropertyParcels", 'parcelnumb')
    for row in rows:
        parcelList.append(row[0])
    # Add join
    points = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation(SitePoints, "INTERSECT", 
adjacentSelection)
    # Spatial Join
    arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(
        target_features="RCRASitePropertyParcels",
        join_features=points,
        out_feature_class="outJoin",
        join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY",
        field_mapping="Coordinate \"Coordinate\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,Coordinate,0,255;HANDLER_ID \"HANDLER_ID\" true true false 
255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,HANDLER_ID,0,255;HANDLER_NAME \"HANDLER_NAME\" 
true true false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,HANDLER_NAME,0,255;LONGITUDE 
\"LONGITUDE\" true true false 8 Double 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,LONGITUDE,-1,-1;LATITUDE \"LATITUDE\" true true false 8 
Double 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,LATITUDE,-1,-1;ACTIVITY_LOCATION 
\"ACTIVITY_LOCATION\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,ACTIVITY_LOCATION,0,255;REGION \"REGION\" true true false 4 
Long 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,REGION,-1,-1;CONTACT_CITY \"CONTACT_CITY\" true true 
false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,CONTACT_CITY,0,255;CONTACT_STREET1 
\"CONTACT_STREET1\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,CONTACT_STREET1,0,255;LOCATION_COUNTY_NAME 
\"LOCATION_COUNTY_NAME\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,LOCATION_COUNTY_NAME,0,255;CONTACT_STREET_NO 
\"CONTACT_STREET_NO\" true true false 255 Text 0 
0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,CONTACT_STREET_NO,0,255;Lat_Long \"Lat_Long\" true true 
false 255 Text 0 0,First,#,SitePointsLayerLatLong,Lat_Long,0,255")  
    # add layer to map
    aprxMap.addDataFromPath(arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + "outJoin")
    # Dissolve
    aprxMap.clearSelection()
    dissolve = arcpy.management.Dissolve("outJoin", handlerName.title())
    # remove handlerID layer
    listLayers = aprxMap.listLayers()
    for l in listLayers:
        if l.name == handlerName.title():
            aprxMap.removeLayer(l)
    # Edit Symbology
    aprxMap.addDataFromPath(arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + handlerName.title())
    poly = aprxMap.listLayers(handlerName.title())[0]
    sym = poly.symbology
    sym.updateRenderer('SimpleRenderer')
    sym.renderer.symbol.applySymbolFromGallery('Black Outline')
    sym.renderer.symbol.size = 2
    poly.symbology = sym
    # Zoom to layer
    cam = aprx.activeView.camera
    ext = arcpy.Describe(dissolve).extent
    cam.setExtent(ext)
    # Export map to image
    for lyr in listLayers:
        if lyr.name == 'adjacentParcels' or lyr.name == 'outJoin':
            aprxMap.removeLayer(lyr)
    aprxMap.clearSelection()
    aprxMap.defaultView.exportToJPEG(jpgPath + "\\" + handlerName.title(), 1221, 835)

# remove def query
for lyr in aprxMap.listLayers():
    if lyr.name == SitePoints:
        lyr.definitionQuery == None

# add fields
arcpy.management.AddFields(handlerName.title(),"#",
                            r"X:\GIS\_Projects\Non-Superfund\RCRA\2024\2024 RCRA 
Boundaries\RCRA Boundaries\Phase 1\Batch 
1\RCRA_dissolved_facilities.gdb\Eco_Services_Operations_Houston_Plant")

# update fields
fields = ['EPA_PROGRAM','HANDLER_ID', 'HANDLER_NAME', 'AREA_NAME', 'AREA_NAME_DESCRIPTION', 
'CLEARED_PUBLIC_RELEASE', 'HORIZONTAL_COLL_CODE', 'TIER_ACCURACY_CODE']
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(handlerName.title(), fields)
for row in cursor:
    row[0] = "RCRA CORRECTIVE ACTION"
    row[1] = handlerID
    row[2] = handlerName
    row[3] = "Property parcel(s) # " + str(parcelList).replace('[','').replace(']', 
'').replace("'",'') + " boundary"
    row[4] = areaNameDescription
    row[5] = 'No'
    row[6] = 7
    row[7] = 1
    cursor.updateRow(row)

# calculate geometry
arcpy.management.CalculateGeometryAttributes(
    in_features="Clean_Harbors_Deer_Trail_Llc",
    geometry_property="AREA_ACREAGE AREA_GEODESIC;POLY_AREA_ACREAGE AREA_GEODESIC",
    length_unit="",
    area_unit="ACRES_US",

 
coordinate_system='PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",0.0],PARAMETER["Auxiliary_Sphere_Type",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]',
        coordinate_format="SAME_AS_INPUT"
)


Please [edit] your question to include the error code as text rather than as an image.  Also try focusing your script to a snippet that focuses on just the part that's failing and include that snippet of code here instead of all of it.

See https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-python-questions/http-error-413-request-entity-too-large/td-p/870917 for info about Error 413: Request Entity too Large
